I get error: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
I am trying to run a .launch file, while my STM32 Bluepill is loaded from the Arduino IDE.
First I though the issue would be due to packages. I already had the ros_lib installed and all the board managers for the Bluepill, so I tried doing it through the package of the STM32 following this tutorial: https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/wiki/Getting-Started. Yet after adjusting all the files so that this can run on my IDE, I fall back to the same issue of:
[ERROR] [1715282709.474070]: Unable to sync with device; 
possible link problem or link software version mismatch such 
as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino.

I tried adjusting the baud rates on my .launch file to 9600, 57600, and 11250 but that didn't make a difference. I tried changing the baud rate on my port, but I did not let me change it on my laptop.
So I am now a bit lost on what to do.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?
